# How to add "AddType application/x-httpd-php .html" line in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file through command not manually?

Tags: apache2

I want to deploy my PHP website in Ubuntu Virtual Machine in Azure. I am downloading the website zip file from Azure blob storage and copying it to /var/www/html/ using below command.

```
wget https://acmesanappstor0.blob.core.windows.net/appmigration/Online_Shopping.tar.gz
tar -xzvf Online_Shopping.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/Online_Shopping
sudo cp -r ~/Online_Shopping/* /var/www/html/Online_Shopping
```

Now I have to add "AddType application/x-httpd-php .html" line at the end of  sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file automatic through command line. I am putting all the command in one script file and that script file is used to deploy my website automatically.
I have written the below script file for my website deployment.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
apt-get -y update

# set up a silent install of MySQL
dbpass=$1

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
echo mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password password $dbpass | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password_again password $dbpass | debconf-set-selections

# install the LAMP stack
apt-get -y install apache2 mysql-server php5 php5-mysql  

wget https://acmesanappstor0.blob.core.windows.net/appmigration/Online_Shopping.tar.gz
tar -xzvf Online_Shopping.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/Online_Shopping
sudo cp -r ~/Online_Shopping/* /var/www/html/Online_Shopping
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
****AddType application/x-httpd-php .html***
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Please help me, how I will add the line in an automated process.

Comment: as you running your script with sudo allready adding the line `echo "AddType application/x-httpd-php .html" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to end of your script should be enough...

Comment: @IvanTemchenko I would suggest making that into an answer so that you can get rep :P

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help :P

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am successfully deployed my PHP website in Azure Ubuntu VM. Now I need one more help from you. I have to connect my website DB with Azure MySQL DB. So I have to edit the config.php file through command, not manually. My file is present in /var/www/html/temp/ folder. I am using the below syntax to edit the file. "echo "hostname us-cdbr-azure-west-c.cloudapp.net" >> /var/www/html/temp/config-sample.php"

Comment: But it's adding the whole line at the end of the file. Please advice me some command, so that I will edit my file through command line

Answer (score 0):

as i see from this script your passing the password with the script like if the script is script.sh your running the script as

```
 sudo -i
./script.sh yourmysqlpassword #assuming the script is in current directory
```

i edited it to your needs just appending the line will do the job

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get -y update

# set up a silent install of MySQL
dbpass=$1

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
echo mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password password $dbpass | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password_again password $dbpass | debconf-set-selections

# install the LAMP stack
apt-get -y install apache2 mysql-server php5 php5-mysql  

wget https://acmesanappstor0.blob.core.windows.net/appmigration/Online_Shopping.tar.gz
tar -xzvf Online_Shopping.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/Online_Shopping
sudo cp -r ~/Online_Shopping/* /var/www/html/Online_Shopping
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
###AddType application/x-httpd-php .html###
echo "AddType application/x-httpd-php.html" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

run the script as root so echo doesn't complain

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am successfully deployed my PHP website in Azure Ubuntu VM. Now I need one more help from you. I have to connect my website DB with Azure MySQL DB. So I have to edit the config.php file through command, not manually. My file is present in /var/www/html/temp/ folder. I am using the below syntax to edit the file.               "echo "hostname us-cdbr-azure-west-c.cloudapp.net", "dbuser sandy" dbpassword hsjdj@1234" >> /var/www/html/temp/config-sample.php". But it's adding the whole line at the end of config file.

Comment: Please advice me some command, so that I will edit my file through command line.

Comment: just open the file with any text editor like vim or nano, 

write it  like this nano yourfilename when done ctrl+x to exit it will ask for saving changes press y or n then exit

Comment: if my naswer helped you, then choose as answer ,give vote to it so others can find this easily seeing it solved